# How non-elite bosses from Adventurer Handbook are different from their normal versions?

Tags: genshin-impact

Adventurer Handbook has "Bosses" tab:

[image]

It has:

- weekly bosses,
- 40 resin "elite" bosses;
- "regular" bosses.

How are these regular bosses different from the same enemies your can find in open world? Do they drop better loot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They are the open world enemies**

The navigate function helps you find ones that are currently available. This is helpful when you haven't marked on your map all the locations for Whopperflowers or Ruin guards. If you are having trouble finding a certain boss (or a certain advancement material) simply use the book to navigate.

Comment: Additionally, if you need to farm a specific boss, you can do it in multiplayer. I recommend putting a pin on your map for each of the bosses you're farming as you fight them in your world, then once you've fought them all join a friend (or random other person who is willing to let you farm theirs) and revisit the locations in their world(s).